# Not sure about this style of jQuery/Javascript proramming.

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototyping

Im wanting to do a tutorial for my blog/portfolio site and I realized that... For all I know about this particular method of jQuery/Javascript programming, I do not know what to call it or what other people call it. I know its a particular method of OOP and the person who showed me how to do this referred to it as "Prototyping". But when searching for it on google, im not finding anything similar. Here is condensed example:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
site.internal.page = function () {
    return {                        
        init: function () {

            var that = this;                            

        },
        business: function () {
            return {
                init: function () {

                },
                doSomething: function () {                                                  

                },  
                        addSomething: function (r) {

                },
                makeSomethign: function () {

                }                                   
            }
        }(),
        invoice: function () {
            return {
                init: function () {         
                    that = this;                

                },
                addItem: function (row) {


                }
            }
        }()
    }
}();

site.internal.page.init();
});
```

Can anyone assist me in figuring out what to refer to this as. Im not sure if its the same as making a library or a plug-in, but id really like to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: There are many things going on there, which one are you referring to?

Comment: Everything as a whole. Im asking why my friend would refer to it as "Prototyping" or am I mis-understanding him?

Comment: I've never heard that before. It could mean modifying object prototypes, but there's none of that going on here.

Comment: Here is the explanation of it. I knew there way a design pattern associated with this: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/ This is a design pattern called Javascript Module Pattern and it is a fantastic way of writing code. Works great with jQuery.

Comment: Good find. In the spirit of this site, you should post this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating anonymous functions and storing a reference to each in a variable.

Comment: Is this not a particular coding style? Like, is there a name for the method of coding?

Answer (score 0):

If refereing to the `site.internal.page` part, I would suggest this is an attempt to namespace the javascript in a large site.

Comment: I understand the namespace aspect of it. But is this a style of coding? For example MVC is a style of coding for PHP.

Comment: No, MVC is a pattern for software development, not specific to PHP. I don't think there is a specific name like that for this code you've posted.

Comment: Its called Javascript Module Pattern:  http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Comment: @Chris - possibly what *that guy* calls it, but what he describes is just namespacing!